# Is it possible to use CheckConstraint on model instance in the django shell?

Tags: django, django-models, check-constraints

I have a model and want to apply a constraint on it to ensure only sensible values get to be stored in the model.

The model along with the constraint I am using looks somewhat like this (simplified)

```py
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):

    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        ('UnderWay', 'UnderWay'),
        ('Processed', 'Processed'),
        ('Entrusted', 'Entrusted')
    )

    action = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='UnderWay', choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
    entrusted_to = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='Name of the department/person entrusted to')
    # some other fields

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=(
                    (models.Q(action='Entrusted') & (models.Q(entrusted_to__isnull=False) | ~models.Q(entrusted_to=''))) |
                    ((models.Q(action='UnderWay') | models.Q(action='Processed')) & (models.Q(entrusted_to__isnull=True) | models.Q(entrusted_to='')))
                ), #more complex conditions in actual
                name='constraint_on_et'
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} - {self.action}'
```

**Makemigrations** and **migrate** ran successfully. But, when I try to create new instances through the shell, the constraint fails in cases that weren't meant to be. I looked at the coded constraint again and it looks fine to me.

So, I tried to break the constraint(*constraint_on_et*) into simpler conditions to see which one actually fails.
As the table is already populated, I am not able to check some specific parts of the constraint(they are always meant to fail on current data).

Out of curiosity, I thought if I could apply a [CheckConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint), directly on a single instance of the model stored in the database rather than applying it on the whole model. On the shell, I was able to easily create a CheckConstraint object like:

```py
c = models.CheckConstraint(
        check=(
            (models.Q(action='Entrusted') & (models.Q(entrusted_to__isnull=False) | ~models.Q(entrusted_to='')))
        ),
        name='temp_constraint'
    )
```

But, after this, I couldn't see a way to apply this on a Task instance. Looked over the internet and into the [implementation of CheckConstraint](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/constraints.py), but there doesn't seem to be a way for it.

So, my question is, is there any way I could achieve the following? If not, are there any alternatives I could use?

I can save a copy of the current database and test on a separate clean one, but that might not be always feasible.

*Note*: I am using Django 3.2.10 with db.sqlite3 as the current database.

Comment: What was the case that failed but wasn't meant to, and what is the full constraint that shouldn't have failed?

Comment: To give a brief idea, the use case is that earlier Task did not have 'Entrusted' action and the entrusted_to field. So, no row in existing data has the 'Entrusted' action and entrusted_to field ('' for every row). This does not give any constraint error but when I pick one of the Instances and change its action to 'Entrusted' and entrusted_to to some string value, the constraint fails on save, which shouldn't had as per logic.

Comment: CheckConstraints are generally not checked by Django and it's left to the DB to raise an error. I am unable to replicate your issue with the data/constraint you have provided, I can save objects with the data you describe, could you provide the actual constraint/model? Are you just looking to test/validate your constraint(s) in a shell?

Comment: @IainShelvington My bad it does work [and my actually still doesn't], but I only put it here for representational purposes.
And, yes, I am just looking for a way to validate constraints in a shell.

Comment: If you have a test/replica DB and remove the constraint you could test constraints using some version of: `obj = Task.objects.create(action='Entrusted', entrusted_to='foo'); obj_passes_constraint = Task.objects.filter(<constraint_check>).filter(pk=obj.pk).exists()`

Comment: Thanks, this works! But, can you convert this into an answer so that I can accept it.